# How to redirect commands to a raspberry from an android App?

Tags: node.js

I have a trial version of a VPS, I want to use this as a server to send commands from a smartphone to the raspberry.

I am using http to send requests to the VPS but how can I redirect the commands received from the smartphone to the raspberry?

Comment: give me a minute I'll answer to this

Comment: You can have the raspberry connect a socket to the VPS (either webSocket or just a regular socket) and then you can send data over that socket form VPS to the raspberry PI at any time.  Or, you could make the raspberry PI be a web server and just make ajax calls directly from the smartphone to the raspberry PI without even using the VPS.

Comment: open a socket, this is what i looking for.
I would avoid using the rasp as server.

Answer (score 2):

You can code a client-side script in Python which reads the response from the VPS each 2 seconds (or other time) and execute the command you want. E.g.

### client-side script (read.py)

```
#client example

import socket, time
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('theVPSip', 80)) # port 80 by default
TIME = 2 # amount of time to wait. Do not saturate VPS server
while 1:
    time.sleep(TIME)
    data = client_socket.recv(512)
    print "RECIEVED:" , data
    import subprocess
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
```

### server-side script

Depending on what language you code, you will use a different syntax (of course). But I'll tell you what you have to do:

1. Register the Raspberry IP into a variable (only first time, experimenting, then let it fixed)
2. Register to-be-sent commands in a database
3. Check if the request comes from the RPi or from the phone.

   1. RPi-> send command to execute as a return in plain text
   2. Phone-> register data (taken from POST/GET request) into database

I suppose you could communicate with the raspberry using other model, but you would need to have a bigger control to the server and be able to run scripts of the kind of a socket connection (e.g. using Python/Java)

Comment: Nice! I have not thought of storing the 'IP address. I am using javascript with node.js for now.I'm curious to know if there are other possibilities to communicate with the raspberry..